# Why does Rust's Cargo not consider version 0.8.3 to have a compatible API with version 0.9.0?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm reading the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). Specifically [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#using-a-crate-to-get-more-functionality) about Semantic Versioning used by Cargo.

What doesn't really make sense is this:

> The number 0.8.3 is actually shorthand for ^0.8.3, which means any
> version that is at least 0.8.3 but below 0.9.0. Cargo considers these
> versions to have public APIs compatible with version 0.8.3, and this
> specification ensures you'll get the latest patch release that will
> still compile with the code in this chapter. Any version 0.9.0 or
> greater is not guaranteed to have the same API as what the following
> examples use.

According to the rules for [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), a change of the minor version (from `0.8.3` to `0.9.0`) can NOT contain changes that break the public API. Why does Cargo think that the public API for these 2 versions may not be compatible? Is it because the major version happens to be 0? If we were dealing with a case where the major version was > 0 (Ex. `1.8.3`), would specifying `1.8.3` in `Cargo.toml` allow Cargo to install version `1.9.0` then?

Comment: *According to the rules for semantic versioning, a change of the minor version (from 0.8.3 to 0.9.0) can NOT contain changes that break the public API.* - This is not true, see rule 4. Everything numbered 0.x.y is not stable API and can change.

Comment: @user4815162342 I literally mentioned that case in my question, and ask if that was the reason

Comment: The section of the book in question states what Cargo will do, but doesn't mention that this will only happen if the major version is `0`, implying that this is how Cargo always behaves. That Cargo will consider `1.8.3` incompatible with `1.9.0`. Either the book doesn't explain this in enough detail, uses a bad example with a major version of `0` (which is the exception, rather than the rule), or I'm missing something.

Comment: The example may be flawed, or the explanation insufficient, but my comment was referring to the specific sentence of your question which is IMO just incorrect. You do mention the case of major version 0 later, but don't mention that that is also mandated by semver, so the wording makes it sound (to me at least) like describing a quirk in cargo.

Comment: *You're nitpicking the wording, rather than trying to answer the question* - It's not nitpicking, your wording makes it sound like you found a bug where cargo diverges from semver, which is just false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the [Specifying Dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) chapter of The Cargo Book (emphasis added):

> The string `"0.1.12"` is a [semver](https://github.com/steveklabnik/semver#requirements) version requirement. Since this string does not have any operators in it, it is interpreted the same way as if we had specified `"^0.1.12"`, which is called a caret requirement.
>
> #### Caret requirements
>
> **Caret requirements** allow SemVer compatible updates to a specified version. ***An update is allowed if the new version number does not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the major, minor, patch grouping.***
>
> [...]
>
> This compatibility convention is different from SemVer in the way it treats versions before 1.0.0. While SemVer says there is no compatibility before 1.0.0, Cargo considers `0.x.y` to be compatible with `0.x.z`, where `y ≥ z` and `x > 0`.

Comment: Not only is the middle paragraph of the book you are quoting confusing, but it also tries to answer the question "what does Cargo do?", rather than my question about why Cargo does what it does. If anything, the 3rd paragraph states that having 0 as the major version shouldn't make Cargo behave differently then if it was > 0, which means it appears to behave strangely in ALL cases - not just in cases where the major version is 0.

Comment: @John: As mentioned in the comments above, [rule 4 of the semantic versioning specification](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4) treats major version 0 as unstable. NPM introduced [caret ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004): "*Caret ranges are ideal when an author may make breaking changes between 0.2.4 and 0.3.0 releases, which is a common practice. However, it presumes that there will not be breaking changes between 0.2.4 and 0.2.5. It allows for changes that are presumed to be additive (but non-breaking), according to commonly observed practices.*"

Comment: @John: Cargo merely adopted caret ranges from NPM and made them the default when no explicit range specifier is included.  The third quoted paragraph simply explains that this approach differs in its assumptions over the stability of major version 0 releases from rule 4 of the semver spec.  The second quoted paragraph explains the overall effect of this choice, in precisely the same language as NPM used: "*Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the `[major, minor, patch]` tuple.*" What about it do you find confusing?

Comment: @John: Consequently, Cargo **does not** see `0.9.0` as compatible with `"0.8.3"` but it **does** see `0.8.10` as compatible.  This is exactly what your quote in the question from The Rust Book says.  For the avoidance of doubt, `1.9.0` **is** compatible with `"1.8.3"`.

Comment: I think I understand. SemVer says that NONE of the versions below `1.0.0` are compatible with each other. Not even a patch version change (`0.8.3` and `0.8.4`). Cargo says that if only the Patch version changed, it's compatible. Minor version changes are treated by Cargo as per the SemVer rules however - if the major version is `0`, a minor version change stops being compatible, but if the major version is `>0`, a minor version change is still compatible. That sound right?

Comment: @John: Pretty much, but `0.0.2` is **not** compatible with `"0.0.1"`.

Comment: They should really clarify in the rust docs this difference for versions below 1.0.0, I was just as confused as @John and found this question. It all makes sense now after reading this.